# Syntax error with def

Tags: python, python-2.7, syntax, function

I am designing a program to test how fast you can type random quotes. I keep trying to run it, but it keeps giving me a syntax error and highlighting the **def** command. I have tried tampering with the indentations, thinking that is the problem. Here is all of the code:

```
import time, sys, random
random = ["Behind every great man is a woman rolling her eyes.", "A day without  sunshine is like, you know, night.", "If the facts don't fit the theory, change the facts.","Housework can't kill you, but why take a chance?", "Weather forecast for tonight: dark."
def main():          
 ready = raw_input("Are you ready to begin?")
 if ready == 'yes' or 'y':
    print "3..."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "2..."
    time.sleep(1)
    print "1..."
    time.sleep(1)
    now = time.time()
    quote = random.choice(random)
    print quote
    enter = raw_input()
    future = time.time()
    time = future - now
    if enter == quote:          
        correct = "You had no mistakes."
    else:
        correct = "You had mistake(s)."
    quote2 = len(quote)
    wordlen = quote2 / 5
    print "Results:"
    print "The quote was "+quote2+" letters long and approx. "+wordlen+" words long."+correct+"Good job!"

if ready == 'no' or 'n':
    print "Take your time."
    sys.exit()
else:
    print "What was that?"
    main()
```

Comment: READ: The error shown is fixed, but now it says "UnboundLocalError: local variable 'time' referenced before assignment" on ln 7.

Comment: Your comment should have been a new question, posted separately. Now you have answers to two completely different questions under this one question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your other error comes from using `time = future - now`.

Don't use the module name as a variable name, you have also done this using `random` as your list name.

Change `time = future - now` to something like `time_diff = future - now`

Change `random` as your list name to something like `random_list` changing it in your code also.

Keep in mind `if` statements are always evaluated so  the the order of your statements matter, if you have two conditions to check use `if/elif` as if the first `if` is `True` you don't need to evaluate the second statement.  `elif` statements are only evaluated if the first `if` statement is False.

This code will work:

```
import  time,sys, random
# changed name from random to random_list
random_list = ["Behind every great man is a woman rolling her eyes.", "A day without  sunshine is like, you know, night.", "If the facts don't fit the theory, change the facts.","Housework can't kill you, but why take a chance?", "Weather forecast for tonight: dark."]
def main():
    ready = raw_input("Are you ready to begin?")

    if ready == 'yes' or ready =='y': # need to use or ready =='y' not or == "y"
        print "3..."
        time.sleep(1)
        print "2..."
        time.sleep(1)
        print "1..."
        time.sleep(1)
        now = time.time()
        quote = random.choice(random_list)
        print quote
    elif ready == 'no' or ready =='n':# moved from bottom to here and changed to elif.
        print "Take your time."
        sys.exit()
    else:
        print "What was that?"
        main()
    enter = raw_input("Enter the quote: ")
    future = time.time()
    time_diff = future - now # changed name to time_diff instead of time
    if enter == quote:
        correct = "You had no mistakes."
    else:
        correct = "You had mistake(s)."
    quote2 = len(quote)
    wordlen = quote2 / 5
    print "Results:"      # quote2 and wordlen are ints you need to cast as strings to join to another string.
    print "The quote was "+str(quote2)+" letters long and approx. "+str(wordlen)+" words long."+correct+"Good job!"


main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I also discovered that `time_diff` didn't point to anything :P I now have this bug where it prints "Take your time" when you finish. Don't worry, I'll get it.

Comment: @user2352923,you're welcome.  I have edited the code, not fully sure what you are doing but it should get you closer, you had a few more errors that I commented on in the code.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't close your list:

```
random = ["Behind every great man is a woman rolling her eyes.", "A day without  sunshine is like, you know, night.", "If the facts don't fit the theory, change the facts.","Housework can't kill you, but why take a chance?", "Weather forecast for tonight: dark."]
```

Comment: Whoops. Totally missed that. 
T

Comment: Thank you so much (accidentally hit enter in last comment)